# display users alhpabetically In magento

Tags: php, magento, sorting, zend-framework

Hi i have fetch the users on frontend and filter them with some attribute below is the code

```
$userid =  Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId();
$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('main_supplier',$userid)
->load();
```

this works fine but

> i need to display the users alphabetically

, can you please suggest how can i do this please suggest

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have multiple records where user of main_supplier is multiple,

Just add below query with collection to sort user from his/her first name from customer model

```
$model = Mage::getSingleton('customer/customer');
$result = $model->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
         ->addAttributeToFilter('main_supplier', array('eq' => $userid))
          ->addAttributeToSort('firstname', 'ASC');

foreach($result as $r) 
{       
        $customer = $model->load($r->getId());
        echo PHP_EOL,'<b>'.$customer->getFirstname().' '.$customer->getLastname().' '.$customer->getEmail(),PHP_EOL;
}
```

above example is working for me, hope this will sure help you.

let me know if i can assist you further.